# Pass GET or POST Information with FullCalender jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following Full Calender jQuery based code which I want to sent a customer ID to my feed file. The customer ID will let me tailor my feed file to only calender data for this client.

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: {
  url: 'myfeed.php?uid=<? echo $UID; ?>',
  data: function() { // a function that returns an object
        return {
            uid: '<? echo $UID; ?>'
        };
    },
    },
header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    async: false,
eventSources: [

// your event source
{
    url: 'myfeed.php?uid=<? echo $UID; ?>', // use the `url` property
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
    custom_param1: '<? echo $UID; ?>'
    },
    color: 'red',    // an option!
    textColor: 'black'  // an option!
}
// any other sources...
],
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
$(".caccount").css("display", "block");
}
});     
});
</script>
```

And this is my feed file.

```
[<?php
//grab all this clients appointments and build the array
if(isset($_GET'uid']) || isset($_POST['uid'])){
$AddedTime = 30 * 60 * 60;
$arr = array(
'id' => '1', 'title' => 'Apples', 'allDay' => false, 'start' => '1393147825', 'end' =>         '1393199825'
);
echo json_encode($arr);
}?>]
```

I know this is FullCalender specific, but I know I am doing something wrong. My UID is correctly set to 'aw5nw35nawn5awn5'.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: How do I find my errors?

Answer (score 0):

My condition $_GET'uid'] was missing a [

._.